# Exception "Could not connect to the database: No suitable driver found for Database" in viewing Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, netbeans-7

I am using jasper reports 4.5.1. I just included all the dependencies required for jasper-reports-4.5.1. I am getting the following exception

```
Could not connect to the database: No suitable driver found for CatalogNew No suitable driver found for CatalogNew.
Apr 26, 2012 1:01:51 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter <init>
WARNING: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null.
```

on executing following code.

```
  databaseName=ReportDriver.databaseName;
  userName=ReportDriver.userName;
  password=ReportDriver.password;
 Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
 jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseName,userName,password);
```

I also included the database lib jtds.1.2.5 in the lib folder of IReport-4.5.1 installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `ReportDriver.databaseName` contains a database *name* ("CatalogNew"), not a JDBC *URL*.

But the method `DriverManager.getConnection()` expects a JDBC **URL**.

Most probably you'll need to do something like this:

```
String baseURL "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/";
jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(baseURL + databaseName,userName,password);
```

You will need to replace `localhost` with the name of the server running your SQL Server instance.

For more details on the connection URL see the jTDS documentation:
http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat

Comment: Thanks it works but now it displays another error message Could not create the report java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: Thanks it works but now it displays another error message Could not create the report java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: please give my question upvote as i also accpted your answer @a_horse_with_no_name